# Passing string from one to another class

Tags: java

Problem is, when I run the program I don't see output result (means blank in Console window) & no error message or warnings. Can anyone tell me, whats wrong?

```
public class Test1 {

    static String temp = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test2 var = new Test2();
        temp = var.DBType("Australia", "Melbourne");
        System.out.println("Main class: "+temp);
    }
}

package individualFunctionTest;

public class Test2 {

    public String DBType(String dbType, String dtMap) {

        System.out.println("Country to: " +dbType+" "+dtMap);
        dbType = "India";
        dtMap = "Bangalore";
        return dbType;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have run your code, it showing output for me? check is your console is really blank?

Comment: Can you tell us what you expect? If I run the Program output is: `Main class: India`

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or Netbeans? Maybe, you must switch the console output

Comment: I am able to see the output when I execute the code. How are you executing ?

Comment: I can run the code, it outputs correctly

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.
Are both classes in the same package ? Are you sure you are using the right class ? Did you save the classes after altering them ? Did you recompile them ?

Comment: Are using eclipse? check run configurations

Comment: Is your application compiling? is classes get modified when you build ?check that first

Comment: Thank you everyone for responses.

Seems like there is some problem with my compiler or machine because I got result displayed after long time. Don't know what's wrong need to check.

Stultuske > yes both classes in same package.